# Natural Deduction proof using basic rules only

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I need some assistance solving what seems to be a very [intuitive problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arMiv.png), but becomes tough when only using strict natural deduction and not assuming De Morgan laws.

Laws allowed: Implication, And, Or, MT, PBC, Copy Rule, Negation, Double Negation, Contradictions, law of excluded middle

I'm thinking it uses the law of excluded middle but I can't quite figure it out.

$$ \lnot(P \land \lnot Q), \; (\lnot P \to S) \land \lnot Q \;\;\; \text{premises} \tag{1} $$

$$ T \lor S \;\;\; \text{conclusion} \tag{2} $$

Comment: Please copy-paste the formulas into the text... they are only two.

Comment: I added the formulas as mathjax. There's a tutorial and reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

1. $\lnot (P \land \lnot Q)$ --- premise
2. $(\lnot P \to S) \land \lnot Q$ --- premise
3. $\lnot Q$ --- from 2) by $(\land \text E)$
4. $P$ --- assumed [a]
5. $(P \land \lnot Q)$ --- from 4) and 3) by $(\land \text I)$

> 6. Contradiction !

and so on, deriving the sought conclusion: $T \lor S$.

The Natural Deduction rules needed, in addition to the $\land$-rules above, are $(\lnot \text I), (\to \text E)$ and $(\lor \text I)$.

Comment: Thanks boss, ended up getting it because of you. u the man

Answer (score 0):

[My proof here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPvEk.png). Let me know if you see anything wrong with it, or if there's a more efficient way

Comment: On line 4, just assert `¬P∨P` and so on line 8 you need only assume `P`.  There is no need for the double negation elimination.

Comment: Indeed you do not need LEM at all.  Since you can derive a contradiction when you assume `P`, you have an Indirect Proof of `¬P` and so may infer `S` from `¬P →S`.